Are there any surface pad sensors which give the X and Y coordinates of where it is pressed?
I am trying to create a kids toy where the user presses on a pad and stuff happens (not entirely laid out) depending on where the user presses. X, Y coordinates are sent to the microcontroller assuming the origin is at the center of the pad surface.
Surface tactile sensors and 2D pressure sensors have caught my attention but they don't give the coordinates from what I understand.
What options do I have? The best I could think of is using piezoelectric sheet to meausure changes in capacity/resistance to compute the coordinates. But I would like to hear some thoughts from people with experience.

Cross-posted. Please do not cross-post.

Welcome to Robotics RajaKrishnappa, but I'm afraid that shopping questions really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the Robotics question checklist for details of how to write a good question.

As Christian Fritz mentions below, you could use a touch screen like this (and Adafruit has a library that will give you x/y positions), but how big should it to be? Should it be transparent, what forces, price range, etc. Once you finalize the project you'll have some specifications and probably find that nothing meets your exact needs, so it'll be up to you to pick what you compromise on. This is why it's off-topic: it's specific to you and your application.

You can buy the touch-layer of a touch-screen separately from the screen and I think that's exactly what you want. Begs the question why not just use a touch-screen (or cheap tablet).
